# On Non-Admin Account OpenSCManager() function returns null

Tags: c++

Please help me soon.
I am writing a c++ code to run a service, it works fine on administrator account
but on Non-Admin user account, OpenSCManager() function return null.
Please tell me how to grant permission to non-admin user account to start and stop services.
Or do i need to do something else.
Please reply soon

Comment: What does GetLastError() API call return after you get the NULL? If using Visual C++, you can put a breakpoint on the OpenSCManager() call, do a 'Step' and the put '@err' in the Watch window - what is the value?

Answer (score 12):

Probably you're calling `OpenSCManager` specifying the `SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS` flag, which actually requires a set of privileges that are given by default only to admins. To start/stop services here you just need to specify the `SC_MANAGER_CONNECT` flag, which is given by default to any authenticated user.

Now that you have a handle to the service manager, you have to use `OpenService` to get a handle to the service. To have rights to start/stop the service you should specify `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_EXECUTE` as desired access (actually I think you can even narrow down the needed rights to just `SERVICE_START` and `SERVICE_STOP` and, if necessary, `SERVICE_INTERROGATE`).

*Here* is the problem: standard services DACL don't grant such rights to normal users, so you should change the DACL of the service you need to start to allow normal users to start/stop it; see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684215%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). For more info about access rights for services, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685981%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

If, instead of a single service, you want to allow a normal user to start/stop any service, I don't know if it is possible without changing all the DACLs, but in my opinion it's definitely a bad idea.

Note that even in the single service case, if the service is running under a privileged account (e.g. `LocalSystem`) or if it's a vital system service, letting unprivileged users mess with it it's still a bad idea. You should allow users to start/stop only services that aren't all that important for the system.

Out of curiosity, why do you need to let users start/stop services?

Comment: Thank you! :) (random text to get to 15 characters)

Comment: For future reference, you can change the permissions on the service manager itself (although it probably isn't a good idea!) e.g., see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907460

Comment: Whay `CreateServiceW` return `5` with `SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE` in non-admin?